# Why can't Selenium find this class on Wikipedia?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to pull a table from wikipedia. When I try and pull it using the following `driver.find_element_by_class_name(name)` it will not work. However when going to the html source code I can explicitly see the class name that I am looking for.

I do realize there are other ways to pull this table and I have moved on to easier ways. I am curious as to why Selenium does not find the class when it is in the HTML.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_the_United_States')
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

driver.find_element_by_class_name(name='wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter')
```

However, the error I get is

```py
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

Comment: `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter` is 3 class names: wikitable, sortable, and jquery-tablesorter. `.find_element_by_class_name()` only takes a single parameter consisting of a single class name, e.g. `find_element_by_class_name('wikitable)`. That may or may not find the element you want based on whether that class name uniquely locates the element that you want.

Comment: @JeffC this answers my question best. I did not know that spaces makes multiple classes.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I added it as an answer, expanded on it a bit, and added some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter` is 3 class names: wikitable, sortable, and jquery-tablesorter. `.find_element_by_class_name()` only takes a single parameter consisting of a single class name, e.g. `.find_element_by_class_name("wikitable")`. That may or may not find the element you want based on whether that class name uniquely locates the element that you want.

Another option would be to use a CSS selector so that you can use all three classes in a single locator, e.g.

```
.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter
```

where the `.` indicates a class name in CSS selector syntax. See the CSS selector references below for more info on CSS selectors and their syntax.

[W3C Selectors Overview](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)

[Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

[Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

To handle dynamic element use `WebdriverWait` and `visibility_of_element_located` and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter")))
```

You need to import followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

If you want to print the value of table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_the_United_States')
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter"))).text)
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like that finds the element by CSS_SELECTOR. I wonder why it does not work for CLASS_NAME

Comment: Selenium don’t allow multiple class name to be called by class_name instead of that you should use css selector.

Comment: I think I found a better way to do it. ```x = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter' );
print(x[0].text)``` Do you know why this works?

Comment: How this will work? Are you sure this is this going to work.I don't think so. You have added `.classname` and this is `css selector` syntax not `CLASS_NAME` syntax.However if you are using pycharm editor do CTLR+Click on  `find_elements` and it will navigate you to that function and you can learn more about that function.

Comment: It did work, but you are right, I used the wrong format. I am still confused why it does not find the `class` that I listed. Even when changing it to `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` does not give it time to load?

Comment: if you want to use class_name. just use one class_name like `x = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wikitable')
print(x[0].text)`  OR `x = driver.find_element_by_class_name('wikitable');
print(x.text)`

Answer (score -1):

Please use class name directly in function `find_element_by_class_name()`. So, instead of writing like:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name(name='wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter')
```

Please write like:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter')
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This does not solve the problem. They both run exactly the same.